# No path in sys.path with Python and tcsh

Tags: python, tcsh

I don't have much experience with tcsh, but I am interested in learning. I've been having issues getting Python to see `PYTHONPATH`. I can echo `$PYTHONPATH`, and it is correct, but when I start up Python, my paths do not show up in `sys.path`. Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
[dmcdonal@tg-steele ~]$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/home/ba01/u116/dmcdonal/PyCogent-v1.1

>>> from sys import path
>>> from os import environ
>>> path
['', '/apps/steele/Python-2.5.2/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c8-py2.5.egg', '/apps/steele/Python-2.5.2/lib/python2.5/site-packages/FiPy-2.0-py2.5.egg', '/apps/steele/Python-2.5.2', '/apps/steele/Python-2.5.2/lib/python25.zip', '/apps/steele/Python-2.5.2/lib/python2.5', '/apps/steele/Python-2.5.2/lib/python2.5/plat-linux2', '/apps/steele/Python-2.5.2/lib/python2.5/lib-tk', '/apps/steele/Python-2.5.2/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload', '/apps/steele/Python-2.5.2/lib/python2.5/site-packages', '/apps/steele/Python-2.5.2/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Numeric']
>>> environ['PYTHONPATH']
'/apps/steele/Python-2.5.2'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How are you setting PYTHONPATH?  You might be confusing tcsh's set vs. setenv.  Use "set" to set what tcsh calls *shell variables* and use "setenv" to set *environment variables*.  So, you need to use setenv in order for Python to see it.  For example:

```
$ set FOO='bar'
$ echo $FOO
bar
$ python -c 'import os; print os.getenv("FOO")'
None

$ setenv BAR 'wiz'
$ echo $BAR
wiz
$ python -c 'import os; print os.getenv("BAR")'
wiz
```

There is some more information available in [the variables section of the tcsh documentation](http://wings.buffalo.edu/computing/Documentation/unix/tcsh.html).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're not starting python with the `-E` option (which is: ignore environment variables). If you start python via a shell script or some other app, just double check it doesn't add anything.

Since the list of sys.path is long, it can be hard to miss your paths. PYTHONPATH stuff normally gets added to about the middle of the list, after all the library paths. Any chance your paths are there, just buried in the middle?

Comment: definately not in the list and I'm calling the binary directly

Comment: Hmmm... Does it work in any other shell? If you pop into bash, etc, does it work there? What version of Python, btw?

Answer (score 0):

Check:

1. PYTHONPATH is in os.environ,
2. and set to the correct value of a colon separated list of paths.

If it is, and you can confirm that your paths are not in sys.path, you have found a bug.

If it is not in os.environ, your environment is not passing through to Python (probably another bug).

Of course, show us the actual code/exports, and someone will tell you pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue even I set environment `PYTHONPATH` correctly in `.cshrc` when I used Python `2.5.1`, when I switch the to Python `2.6.2`, It works fine. Looks like it is a python bug.